# socket.io keeps opening connections in reactjs application

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, socket.io

I am trying to connect to socket.io connection in my reactjs app.I have a event from which i will recive some data. but my network tab is spammed with lot of connections. my code works fine when i run it on html file using script tags but does this when i do it in react.

here is the react code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("https://serverEndpoint/cart_socket?user_id=52");
    socket.on("get_cart_items", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    return function cleanup() {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return <>socket</>;
}

export default App;
```

here is the screenshots of network tab connections
[connections spam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJB4E.png)
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoTRX.png)

and this is response that i get back
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kglwv.png)

this is the server code for get_cart_items

```
@socketio.on('get_cart_items', namespace="/cart_socket")
def handle_get_cart(message):
    try:
        # emit("get_cart_items", {"sb": "yes"}, broadcast=True)
        if message.get("user_id"):
            room_name = f'cart_update_room_{message.get("user_id")}'
            cart_json = get_cart_items(message.get("user_id"))
            emit("get_cart_items", cart_json, to=room_name)
        else:
            emit("get_cart_items", json_response_view_products({}, "no user_id given", 400, False), to=room_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(f"Disconnected due to:\n {e}")
        disconnect()
```

I have tried adding `tranposrts = ["websockets"]` but it doenot work either it either says closed before connection established or keeps spamming connections with status 101. I have put the connection out of react component at top and also in separate js file both didn't work either. server is in flask python. my socket version at client is 4.7 and at server it is 5. Please help.

Comment: Try turning off the get_cart_items:
        // Cleanup function
        return () => {
          socket.off("get_cart_items", handleGetCartItems);
          socket.disconnect();
        };

Comment: already tried. still same issue

Comment: // Create socket instance outside the component
const socket = io("https://serverEndpoint/cart_socket?user_id=52");

function App() {

Comment: still same issue